# How are parameters for ScriptResource.axd calls generated?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, infragistics

A client has custom firewall rules around their website to prevent any number of attacks. One of the custom rules blocks all requests (either GET or POST) including a double hyphen, in order to prevent SQL injection. While updating their website last night, we had an issue where on every page, one of the calls to the ScriptResource.axd included a double hyphen(--) resulting in access to the script being denied.

We had seen this issue previously and thought we had worked around it by using the ScriptReferenceProfiler in order to generate the list of scripts we'd need to combine in order to remove so many script references. That was working until the update last night when the issue reoccurred. (Interestingly, I reran the ScriptReferenceProfiler and all of the scripts it identified were already included in the CompositeScript listing so I don't know where this file came from.)

I finally created a new IIS virtual directory where the issue with the double dashes didn't occur, despite pointing to the same directory and codebase as the previous virtual directory. (I set the initial virtual directory to act as a redirect to the new one so the users wouldn't have to worry about updating links or bookmarks.) I can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740679/how-does-asp-net-generate-a-scriptresource-axd-url) that the first parameter is generated via encrypting the assembly name and resourcename which explains the difference in the values between the two virtual directories.

But obviously, I'd like to avoid this situation in the future. Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to prevent double dashes from appearing in the ScriptResource requests?

For reference, this occurred in a VB.Net website running in .NET 4.0 on IIS 6/Windows Server 2003. Additionally, the script file being rejected was for an Infragistics control of some sort. (I turned off the firewall rule briefly in order to get the file and then re-enabled it. I wasn't able to tell from the script what role it played for Infragistics, though.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter (d) is the assembly and the resource.  For the assembly, this includes the name and version as well as the public key token if the assembly is strong named.  If any of these change then the string for the resource will also change.

The second parameter (t) is just for the timestamp and this allows the resource to change if an assembly containing an embedded resource is updated without the assembly name or version changing even if caching is enabled on a site.

The encryption of the first parameter is based on the MachineKey so you could change the MachineKey to change the string that results from the encryption.  This may help you to have a simple workaround for the issue when it does come up even if you don't control the names and versions of all of the assemblies that you use.

Related reading that may be of interest to you:

- [machineKey Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations)
- [Debugging ASP.NET 2.0 Web Resources: Decrypting the URL and Getting the Resource Name](http://blogs.telerik.com/hristodeshev/posts/07-03-27/debugging-asp-net-2-0-web-resources-decrypting-the-url-and-getting-the-resource-name.aspx)

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted as it helped me understand more fully what was going on. We eventually spoke to Microsoft and our firewall provider and ended up adding a specific exception to the rules to allow double dashes only on calls to ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd once Microsoft assured us that would not lead to any database attacks. I still don't like that the encryption used by Microsoft results in double-dashes as expected behavior but they didn't want to pursue that option. Thanks for the help.